Coordinate matrix for a basis - More than 1 column?
The problem below asks which matrices are possible for Cb(x).
However, a coordinate basis vector seems to be just one vector, not a matrix. So why would it be a matrix, which I need to select in this problem?


The question is only asking which of these could be a change of coordinate matrix.
You are correct that a coordinate vector is just a vector, but when they write $C_B(x)$ they mean what matrix $C_B$ gives the transformation $\mathbf{x }\mapsto C_B\mathbf{x}$.
(They are basically asking which of these matrices contain a linearly independent, spanning set of columns.)
